# HTML5 Android App - Android Marketplace

Tags: android, html, cordova

We are about to build a new company Android app and would like to code using HTML5, CSS3 and Jquery and then compile with PhoneGap.  We want to do it this was as we already have strong skill-sets available in these areas.

I wonder if anyone could advise whether this would cause any issues in getting our App listed in the Android Marketplace.  Or whether there are any other serious downsides to our approach.

Thanks for your help.

Paul

Comment: I don't think you'd have any problems on the Android market. It's the iPhone app store you'll need to worry about. I started off down the route of developing web apps, but I quickly learned that code becomes unmanageable very quickly - especially if you need to interface with external hardware. I personally think that learning Android/Java pays off and you get a far superior product at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PhoneGap, as I understand it, will not compile the HTML5 code, it will put it inside a nice box.

This is practical because it allows you to use your existing skillset, but it has the inconvenient your still working with a web application, even though you slightly increase your  abilities by accessing the native API through PhoneGap.

You will not have issues with listing on the Marketplace, several applications do that already and have no issue. However, it really depends on your final objective. If your application is basically a form tool, your computational needs are low, and this is the way to go. If it's a marketing tool, it probably is too. However, if you need to do serious math or animation, access some hardware features (like creating overlays on video in realtime with GPS information and accelerometer management), you will need to use the Java API (and maybe even the NDK) to make it manageable and usable.

You will be able to do amazing things with HTML5 of course, but it's really a matter of computing power, interpreted versus compiled-and-optimized. So, once again: it depends on the type of application you plan to build.

Answer (score 1):

Android Market will not give you any issue at all. There are, however, downsides and trade-offs.

There is a pretty good comparison chart here: https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AsTInFQpmXDNdEdJU0ZNNGx3dDA3aXAxV3lXYWhXVHc

My understanding is that the HTML/Javascript/CSS isn't compiled into native code (like Titanium) but is actually just embedded. In that case, you're probably going to be missing out on a bunch of APIs (and I wonder why you don't just do a webapp...?), but if that's ok with you, it should be fine.